# How to rename or remove file name with weird quotes and slashes in linux

Tags: linux, git, github, terminal, rm

When I run `git status` I get:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        "\231"
        "\231\217\373\275\235Y"
```

So I tried to rename/remove it with:

```
~/code$ mv \"\\231\" temp
mv: cannot stat '"\231"': No such file or directory
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I noticed that if I run `ls` instead I get:

```
''$'\231'
''$'\231\217\373\275\235''Y'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: When the shell error reporting shows you a funky named file with an even funkier quoting, .... **use that quoting** (-;! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do something like

```
rm ''$'\231'
```

and

```
''$'\231\217\373\275\235''Y'
```

or you can `mv` them.

Tested and it worked

[image]